# Using riemann integral, calculate following limit of a sequence

Tags: integration

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{1}{n \sqrt{n}}(1+\sqrt3 +\sqrt5 + ...+ \sqrt{2n-1}) $$
Can u give me a hint? I have no idea, I'm trying to convert this as $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt\frac{2k-1}n$$But problem is that I don't know how to determine integer function and boundaries of that(almost)integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\large Riemann\ Sum\ Approach:}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\root{2k - 1 \over n}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n}
\sum_{k = 1}^{2n - 1}\root{k \over n}} -
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\root{2k \over n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{2}x^{1/2}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{4\root{2} \over 3}}\ -\
\underbrace{\root{2}\int_{0}^{1}x^{1/2}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{2\root{2} \over 3}} =
\bbx{2\root{2} \over 3} \\ &
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\large Stolz–Cesàro\ Theorem:}$

With the
[Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\root{2k - 1 \over n}}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\root{2k - 1} \over n^{3/2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n + 1}\root{2k - 1} -
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\root{2k - 1} \over \pars{n + 1}^{3/2} - n^{3/2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\root{2n + 1}
 \over \pars{n + 1}^{3/2} - n^{3/2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}{n^{1/2}\root{1 + 1/\pars{2n}}
 \over n^{3/2}\bracks{\pars{1 + 1/n}^{3/2} - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}{1
 \over n\braces{\bracks{1 + 3/\pars{2n}} - 1}} =
\bbx{2\root{2} \over 3} \\ &\
\end{align}

Comment: I know that's correct but still idk how to do it using integral

Comment: @paweta Thanks. I’ll add something later.

Comment: @paweta Done !!!.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's very comprehensive solution from you. Appreciate it !!

Comment: So basically, u take 2 series,where one is with all natural numbers and you substract the other with only   even numbers, and to do that you do kind of substutution so that still n=(2n-1)-(n-1) and hence  we have boundaries: x=2(because of 2(n) ? and x=1  ?

Comment: @paweta Thanks. That’ s right.